# Triggers(After UPDATE) cause an error?

Tags: sql-server

I am using sql-server 2012 and i wrote a trigger like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ModValue] 
   ON  [dbo].[Table1]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @ocid bigint 
    declare @ncid bigint,@pid bigint

    set @ocid=(select CategoryId from deleted)
    select @ncid=CategoryId,@pid=Id from inserted

    if(@ocid<>@ncid)
    begin
    delete from [Table2] where ProductId=@pid
    delete from [Table3] where ProductId=@pid
    delete from [Table4] where ProductId=@pid
    end
END
```

When i want to update my table(Table1) i got this error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ModValue, Line 15
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery
>   follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an
>   expression. The statement has been terminated.

Update query:

```
update Table1 
set sizing = 0 
where categoryid = 238
```

What is wrong with this scripts?

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. It will fire **once per statement**. If your `UPDATE` statement updates 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then the `Deleted` and `Inserted` pseudo tables will each contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `set @ocid=(select CategoryId from deleted)` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: thank you @marc_s. thats my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following line is the problem:

```
set @ocid=(select CategoryId from deleted)
```

`SET` command expects at most 1 line from the `SELECT` statement. `deleted` table may contain more than 1 line, as trigger will fire at `batch` level, not `record` level.

Answer (score 3):

The `DELETED` and `INSERTED` tables may contain more than one row.

- `DELETED` - contains data that existed before modifications (old)
- `INSERTED` - modified data (new).

So you have to find out where `CategoryID` was changed:

```
... 
from 
    Inserted new 
inner join 
    Deleted old on old.id = new.id 
where 
    new.CategoryID <> old.CategoryID
```

To do something with that while keeping in mind that there could be many rows, for example:

```
delete from [Table2] t2 
where exists (select 1 
              from Inserted new 
              inner join Deleted old on old.id = new.id 
              where new.CategoryID <> old.CategoryID 
                and t2.ProductId = d.ProductID)
```

Note that `ProductID` could be changed by `UPDATE` statement too.